# Why does CakePHP transform POST requests into PUT?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm running CakePHP 4.4.7 using PHP 8.0.23.
I have a controller

```php
class StrawberriesController extends AppController
{
    public function eat($id = null)
    {
        \Cake\Log\Log::debug(json_encode($this->request->getMethod()));
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
        ...
    }
}
```

I have a template with a form

```php
<?= $this->Form->create($entity, [
    'url' => [
        'controller' => 'Strawberries',
        'action' => 'eat',
        $entity->id,
    ],
]) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->text('is_asap') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->submit('now') ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

When I submit the form, the debug line shows

```
2022-11-03 16:58:06 debug: "PUT"{
    "scope": []
}
```

I expected to receive an HTTP POST request. Especially because using the devtools:

- in the elements tab, the `form` element has the attribute `method="post"`
- in the network tab, the HTTP method inside the sent request is a POST

So why is the HTTP method transformed by CakePHP from POST to PUT?
How can I receive a POST request on my controller?

Comment: Is there a problem with just changing to `$this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post', 'put']);`?

Comment: @GregSchmidt A bit. The application could definitely work by allowing `PUT`. However I am sending a `POST`, and the controller does not see it as a `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an entity with an ID (an existing element) in the first parameter of your `$this->Form->create()` CakePHP consider that is an update of your entity. And the convention for an update is to use "PUT" or "PATCH".

You can force the POST method like this :

```php
$this->Form->create($entity, [
     'url' => ['controller' => 'Strawberries', 'action' => 'eat', $entity->id], 
     'type' => 'POST'
]);
```

Doc : https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-form-creation

Comment: @SebastienPuech I'v edited my answer, it's "type" and not "method"